# What's the difference between instancing a class within a class inside or outside __init__?

Tags: python, python-2.7

To be more clear: Is there any difference between "Goodbye" and "Farewell" in this example? Does one hold any advantages over the other?

```
class Hello(object):

    def hi(self):
        pass

class Goodbye(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = Hello()

class Farewell(object):

    hello = Hello()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The difference between the `Goodbye` class and the `Farewell` class is that `Goodbye` has an *instance member* `hello`, while the `Farewell` class has a *class member* `hello`.  If you change the `Hello` class that belongs to a `Farewell` object, then *all* instances of `Farewell` see the change, so you can do this:

```
a = Goodbye()
b = Goodbye()

a.hello.member = 1 # monkey-patching the member
b.hello.member = 2

print(a.hello.member) # prints "1"
print(b.hello.member) # prints "2"

f = Farewell()
g = Farewell()

f.hello.member = 1
g.hello.member = 2

print(f.hello.member) # prints "2"!
```

The reason this works is because, as you have defined it, instances of the `Goodbye` class have their own instance of a `Hello` object, while all instances of the `Farewell` class share the same `Hello` object.  Check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) to learn more!

Now whether or not one holds any advantage over the other is implementation-dependent.  Class members can sometimes be confusing to users who might expect different instances of a class to retain their own state independent of other actions (i.e., mutable class members can break [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).)  However, it might be useful from an efficiency point of view to define members that are constant across all classes (making sure to somehow note this to the users, like hiding them behind underscore prefixes or clear documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
class Hello(object):

    def hi(self):
        print("Hello")

class Goodbye(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = Hello()
        print("this is the Goodbye text")

class Farewell(object):

    hello = Hello()
    print("this is the Farewell text")
```

__init__ is called when the *object* of that class is constructed. So you won't see the text "this is the goodbye text" until you create a Goodbye() object (something like `s = Goodbye()`). However, you will see "this is the Farewell text" when you run your python script containing the Farewell class, but you will NOT see "this is the Farewell text" when you create an object of the Farewell class.